# Python: using map and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a function that can take two arguments and then add it to `multiprocessing.Pool` and parallelize it.
I had some complications when I tried to write this simple function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ind'] = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
df['ind1'] = [111, 444, 222, 555, 777, 333, 666, 777]

def mult(elem1, elem2):
    return elem1 * elem2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4) 
    print(pool.map(mult, df.ind.astype(int).values.tolist(), df.ind1.astype(int).values.tolist()))
    pool.terminate()
```

It's returning an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'list'
```

I can't understand what's wrong.
Can anybody explain what this error means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multi-process Pool module takes in a list of the arguments that you want to multi-process, and only supports taking in one argument.  You can fix this by doing the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ind'] = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]
df['ind1'] = [111, 444, 222, 555, 777, 333, 666, 777]

def mult(elements):
    elem1,elem2 = elements
    return elem1 * elem2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    inputs = zip(df.ind.astype(int).values.tolist(), df.ind1.astype(int).values.tolist())
    print(pool.map(mult, inputs))
    pool.terminate()
```

What I've done here is zip your two iterables into a list with each element being the two arguments that you wanted to input.  Now, I change the input of your function to unpack those arguments so that they can be processed.

Comment: Tempted to set up a test case. Can this not be handled internally by `pandas` to avoid the GIL and run in C? Would the overhead of creating the pool and coordinating it mean that this is an unwise approach (despite fixing the OPs difficulty)?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to create the inputs appropriately in Pandas so that it would scale better.  As far as overhead goes, that will probably be application specific so it would be hard for me to answer.  To be honest, I'm a bit new to using multiprocessing so I don't think I would know the best answer to your questions.  However, I have run into the specific issue that the OP is having.

Comment: I will investigate though I might not be able to get my own test case tonight. Multiprocessing for sure has a big overhead in spawning processes and it's my understanding that this could be vectorised simply... to the point that it invalidates this approach. I upvoted though because you neatly answer the question, I just think the premise of the approach is flawed, but learning myself :)